# Cases of Mathematical Fraud

Tags: soft-question

Are there any cases of *Mathematical Fraud*?

Analogous to other sorts of "scientific misconduct" it could be intentional [1], unintentional [2] or other [4].

[1]: Schoen Scandal http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sch%C3%B6n_scandal

[2]: Psuedo Science http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_topics_characterized_as_pseudoscience

[4]: Bogdanov affair http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bogdanov_affair (A response to Sokal affair http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sokal_affair)

Comment: I don't think this question is suitable for MO.

Comment: What "scientific misconduct" do you see in "Sokal's affair"?

Comment: By "other" I guess I mean as a joke or to highlight problems with academic publishing model.

Comment: What about metaOM? There were some suggestions to expand the scope of OM via *meta*.

Comment: Might be on topic on academia.se, but also less likely to get an answer since there are less mathematicians there.

Comment: Please contact me privately.